# Найти объекты, коллекция которых содержит набор значений

Tags: java, sql, hql, hibernate-criteria

Допустим есть какая-то книга

```
public class Book {
   private Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

И теги

```
public class Tag{
   private String name;
}
```

Между ними связь many-to-many через 3 таблицу (book_tag).
Нужно найти книги, которые содержать заданные теги. То есть допустим Книга1(Тег1), Книга2(Тег1, Тег2, Тег3), Книга3(Тег1, Тег2, Тег4), Книга4(Тег2) и я хочу получить книги содержащие Тег1 и Тег2. То есть ожидаю получить Книгу2 и Книгу 3.

Как можно получить это на SQL & HQL & Criteria?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На SQL это

```
SELECT books.book_id, books.book_title
FROM books
JOIN books_tags USING (book_id)
JOIN tags USING (tag_id)
WHERE tags.name in ('tag-1', 'tag-2')
GROUP BY books.book_id, books.book_title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2
```